# update table by giving old and new entry from query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I select a list of old and new values for a table with a query:

```
select new, old from SOME_TABLE; 

new         old
----------- -----------
1174154     1064267743
1174164     1072037230
1174167     1065180221
1174180     1071828953
1174181     1067402664
1174204     1073143287
1174215     1057480190
1174222     1061816319
1174331     1072011864
1174366     1061275972
```

now i need to update a table that contains these old values and replace them by the new 
ones.

```
update OTHER_TABLE set some_column = <newvalue> where some_column = <oldvalue>
```

Is it possible to do this with one query or do i need to loop over the result tuples and update for each row?

I *cannot* change the database layout or write a trigger that does this automatically...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below:

```
UPDATE OTHER_TABLE t1
SET some_column = (SELECT t2.new FROM SOME_TABLE t2 
                   WHERE t2.old = t1.old_value_column)
```

Just replace `old_value_column` with the column name that hold the old value in `OTHER_TABLE`, along with the other table and column names.

Answer (score 0):

i would not use a subquery as afaik you will select some_table for each row in the table that is to be updated. should the number of rows in both tables be large, you may run into problems. therfore i suggest the update-from method outlined below.

```
update t
set yourcolumn = n.new
from yourtable t
join some_table s
  on t.id = s.old
```